# How do we change the result of groupby into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A" : [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
    "B" : [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    "C": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]})
df
```

This is my data.

and I used

```
gbA = df.groupby("A")
```

How can we change the result of this back to dataframe?

I read the other posts but I still do not get it...

Comment: `df.groupby('A')` only does a *lazy grouping*. What do you want to do with the groups? Sum, average, sample, etc...? Or are you just looking for `df.set_index('A').sort_index()`?

Comment: What do you want from this new dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the original df back, use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with a dummy function:

```
>>> gbA.apply(lambda x:x)
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  2  1  1
2  1  2  1
3  2  2  1
4  1  1  2
5  2  1  2
6  2  1  2
7  1  2  2
```

If you want the groups, use [`dict comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> {k: v for k,v in gbA}
{1:    A  B  C
 0  1  1  1
 2  1  2  1
 4  1  1  2
 7  1  2  2,
 2:    A  B  C
 1  2  1  1
 3  2  2  1
 5  2  1  2
 6  2  1  2}
```

If you want the grouped df, where `A` set as index, use [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html?highlight=set_index#pandas.DataFrame.set_index) `'A'` with `append=True` to keep the original indices intact. Then [`pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html), to swap the multiindex levels, and finally [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html?highlight=sort_index#pandas.DataFrame.sort_index) along `level=0` :

```
>>> df.set_index('A', append=True).swaplevel().sort_index(level=0)
     B  C
A        
1 0  1  1
  2  2  1
  4  1  2
  7  2  2
2 1  1  1
  3  2  1
  5  1  2
  6  1  2
```